# a network of engines that enables Vs that enable

Tags: verb-agreement, subjects

ABC operates **a network of multilingual job search engines that enables** individuals to find suitable jobs across multiple countries.

VS

Recruit.net **operates a network of multilingual job search engines that enable** individuals to find suitable jobs across multiple countries.

Comment: What is your question? Both versions are grammatically correct, though they mean slightly different things.

Comment: My question is the usage of enable/s in the sentence? Which one is the right version according to the rules of subject and verb agreement? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. In the first example, *enables* refers to the singular, *network*. In the second, *enable* refers to the plural *engines*.